# Android audio processing?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I just searched for android 3rd library

doing :-
Synthesis - Oscillators, physical models, generative audio
Playback - Audio files, Sequencing, Sampling
Effects - Processing sound
Filters - Frequency range modification
Analysis - Pitch and loudness detection, FFT spectrum analysis

I found it in iOS Called AudioKit https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit

but can In find some thing like this in Android

Thanks

Comment: To get better intuition about *Audio Processing*, you can visit this reference:
[Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TarsosDSP is one library you should try 
https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP

there is a jar version of this library as well that you can easily import https://github.com/srubin/TarsosDSP/releases/tag/TarsosDSPAndroid-v3-MAD

hope this would work

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Superpowered](http://superpowered.com/). There is lots of stuff there and it's cross-platform -- scroll down the project page for the features chart.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any library in java for this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339328/android-audiorecord-with-channel-in-stereo-read-raw-audio-buffer-resulted-in-mix